# Killing a java process safely on windows

Tags: batch-file, gnu-screen, taskkill

i want to kill a java process through a batch file, but safely.

The problem is, when i use

```
taskkill /IM java.exe
```

it wont kill the process because java doesn't allow it.

When i use

```
taskkill /F /IM java.exe
```

it works, but there is the risk that files could corrupt, so i don't want to use it.

---

The subject is to stop a minecraft server which is running on windows. One option on linux is to use `screen` so i can send a `stop`-command to this virtual command line but as i know this programm doesn't work on windows. Is there mayby an alternative?

Comment: Your question is technically not suitable for StackOverflow, because here we help you to fix a specific replicable issue with your provided code. You don't have a code issue, you're really looking for reference material on alternative methods of performing a task. I'd suggest deleting the question and posting instead on [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Additionally, tag your question correctly. [minecraft] isn't relevant to your question, as you are not making a mod or plugin.

Comment: it is safe to use `taskkill` for local processes as long as you do NOT force it with `taskkill /f` extract of the documentation: __/f : Specifies that process(es) be forcefully terminated. This parameter is ignored for remote processes; all remote processes are forcefully terminated.__